# no sound with qgo go client 16.04

Tags: sound, qt, gstreamer

I have no sound with QGO go client under ubuntu 16.04, and got a terminal output like this:

```
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install **libqt5gstreamer** package.

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Comment: @Steve Lorimer: What's your terminal output? Have you got pulseaudio running?

Comment: Same output as yours, `no service found...`, and I do have pulseaudio running